# Extra whitespace characters getting removed for no reason, when assigning to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

while making a program about capitalizing the first letter of names, i've stumbled across this problem

```py
def solve(s):
    names = s.split()
    for index, name in enumerate(names):
        name_chars = list(name)
        first_letter = name_chars[0]
        if first_letter.isalpha():
            name_chars[0] = first_letter.upper()
            names[index] = "".join(name_chars)
    return " ".join(names)

print(solve(input()))
```

Input:

```
hello  world   LOL
```

Output:

```
Hello World LOL
```

Expected Output:

```
Hello  World   LOL
```

For some reason the spaces are disappearing when they aren't supposed to be, since i need to return the exact same string but only the first letters capitalized.

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on the `split()` function for more information on why your whitespace is disappearing: "If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator"

Comment: Also, look into the [str.title() function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) for cases when you don't have all caps words

Comment: offtopic. `if first_letter.isalpha()` is redundant. if the string can't be upper, it will remain as it was.

Comment: ahh now i get it, this is worth writing down as an answer not a comment, do it and i will mark your answer as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey when you use split without any params
it doesn't consider spaces

use

```
names = s.split(" ")
```

because :

```
In [163]: 'Hello       World'.split()
Out[163]: ['Hello', 'World']

In [164]: 'Hello       World'.split(' ')
Out[164]: ['Hello', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'World']
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

The return line should look like this:

```
return " ".join(names)
```

The space in between the quotes signifies that there should be a space between each element of the array you are joining.

Comment: yeah it is a typo on my part, but still extra spaces are getting removed for some reason

Comment: i specified i want the inputs to be exact with the spaces included, i want to make sure the testcases with extra spaces still output the same exact string with redundant spaces and capitalised first letters

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex with a function replacement:

```
>>> import re
>>> st="hello  world   LOL"
>>> re.sub(r'\b([a-z])', lambda m: m.group(1).upper(), st)
'Hello  World   LOL'
```